# JavaScript print date as UTC and ISO

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, utc

If I do the following:

```
const thisApril = new Date("2019-04-01T00:00:00")
console.log(thisApril.toISODate())
```

The output is `2019-03-31T23:00:00.000Z` because `.toISOString` converts the date from UTC to my time zone. I just want to print the Date as ISO without any time zone conversions.

Comment: Your `new Date(...)` parameter doesn't have a timezone, so it's converting *from* your timezone *to* UTC. Try `new Date("2019-04-01T00:00:00Z");`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks

Comment: "Without any conversions" is not possible, because JavaScript's `Date` object is UTC-based internally.  You are parsing a string that will be recognized as local time, but the `Date` object doesn't retain that.  If you want to create a string in local time, you'll have to do that yourself (see the dup link - strip the offset if you don't want it).  Or you can parse as UTC as Niet suggested if the value is indeed UTC based.